# Flutter: How to dismiss a native viewController and change route in Flutter side

Tags: flutter

I use platform method channel's `invokeMethod`

> Future invokeMethod(String method, [ dynamic arguments ])

to invoke native side to present a ViewController

```
AppDelegate.m:
AViewController vc = [AViewController new];
[SomeRootViewController present:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then I would like to dismiss it when something happened in `AViewController` and after dismiss finished, I'd like to change `route` in Flutter side（like go to another `route`|`screen`).

What's the best way? I should do it from Native side, or I should do it from Flutter side ?

Comment: You are asking 2 questions here, I'm pretty sure you can't change the route from the native code unless you are using an event channel (which means you change the route from flutter). What I would do, I would send an event, on the event channel when the AViewController is dismissed and let flutter decide what to do afterwards.

Comment: @danypata I have checked the `EventChannel`, it's implementation is much more like observe something that keep happening. There's no direct function to call just like `MethodChannel`'s `sendMessage:`. so I think maybe use MethodChannel with callback will be much more suite for this case.